# Code for check if double is a power of 2 without bit manipulation in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, double

For checking if a double is a power of 2 I found this code:

```
unsigned long long int &p= *(unsigned long long int *) &x;
unsigned int exp= (p >> 52) & 0x7FF;
if ( exp == 0 || exp == 0x7FF ) return false;
return (p & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL) == 0;
```

However it fails basic tests for some architectures. I guess that's because different lenght of integers. So I tried to figure out a simple alternative that does not do bit manipulation:

```
bool isPot(double a ){
    return a==0.? false : (1./a)*a==1.;
}
```

The assumption is that any division by a number that is not a power of 2 generates infinite digits in the mantissa, so since values are truncated, it will not yield 1 when multiplied by its inverse.

However, it apparently works, but I cannot proove that because bruteforcing a test for all values would require ~140 years.

Suggestions?

MyTests:

```
assert(isPot(2.0)); //first solution fails here
assert(isPot(0.5));
assert(!isPot(5.0));
assert(!isPot(0.2));
```

By Power of 2, I mean a value that is exactly a power of 2 once stored in RAM. so a number with all mantissa bits that are 0. This is implicitly a solution that has a inherent error because assume the following value:

```
2.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
```

it would be converted to

```
2.0
```

and so returns true because has all mantissa bits to 0, but originally it was not a power of 2.

Comment: when you say 'is a power of 2', how close is acceptable? for example do you consider 7.999999999999999999999999999999 to be a power of 2?

Comment: Nope, I edit the question to make it clear

Comment: By power of two, you mean you can write `a` as 2^x = a ?

Comment: The original version should work - it would be better to identify the problem with it and fix it rather than re-invent the wheel - for what values have you seen it fail ?

Comment: I assume you need it to be very fast - otherwise you could check if log2(x) returns an integer.

Comment: 2^x . so 1/4 is a power of as well as 4 (see the tests in edited question). It fails to recognize 2.0 as power of 2 sometimes.

Comment: @DanByström The does not work because a function to return `log2(x)` is not available, only, at best, one to return the nearest `double` to `log2(x)`, and at worst, a `double` a few ulps from `log2(x)`.

Comment: Then isPot(10) will return true but you can't write 10 as 2^x, can you ?

Comment: I fear log2 would return integer also for values that are not powers of 2. Speed is not a concern, but slow code usually also introduces computations errors that would make that simple test even harder.

Comment: @Thomas, assume x is integer (positive or negative) u.u. Aren't tests explicative enough? :D.

Comment: I've just tested the original code and it seems to work perfectly well - can you provide test code which reliably reproduces the problem? I suspect you may be pointing your finger in the wrong direction and trying to fix a non-existent problem.

Comment: I understand the test, but if you do (1.0/10)*10 == 1 it'll return true, but 10 is 2^3.322

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [frexp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/frexp) as a portable way to split the double into exponent and mantissa, and then check that the mantissa is exactly 0.5.

example:

```
#include <math.h>

bool isPow2(double x)
{
    int exponent = 0;
    auto mantissa1 = frexp(x, &exponent);
    return mantissa1 == 0.5;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(powers_of_2)
{
    std::vector<double> yes { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 0.5, 0.25, 65536 };
    std::vector<double> no { 0, 3, 7, 15, 0.51, 0.24, 65535 };


    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < yes.size() ; ++i) {
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(isPow2(yes[i]), true);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < no.size() ; ++i) {
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(isPow2(no[i]), false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have checked this, confirmed correct. Just be aware that the mantissa of 1.0 is 0.5 (since 1 is 2^0).

Comment: Thanks accepted because is truly portable and because of test case :) (in "my" code I compare mantissa1 with frexp(1.0,&exponent) so that no one should hardcode 0.5)

Comment: To be complete, the return value from `frexp` satisfies `0.5 <= m < 1` for positive finite numbers, satisfies `-1 < m <= -0.5` for negative finite numbers, is a zero of the same sign as its input when fed a zero, is an infinity of the same sign as its input when fed an infinity, and is a NaN when fed a NaN.

Comment: @DarioOO: why don't you want to hard-code `0.5`? `frexp` is standardised, therefore portable.

Comment: because my mate asked why "0.5"? and the answer not conviced him u.u

Answer (score 3):

The [code](https://www.lri.fr/~sboldo/progs/Dekker.c.html) here, named after Dekker, computes the exact error of an IEEE 754 binary64 multiplication (with some restrictions on the arguments).

Barring underflow or overflow, the multiplication of `nextafter(1.0, 0.0)` by `x` is exact iff `x` is zero or a power of two. So you could use the algorithm to compute the exact error of multiplying `nextafter(1.0, 0.0)` by `x` and compare it to `0.0` (with `==`).

Implementing the above idea literally:

```
bool isPow2(double x){
    double y = std::nextafter(1.0,0.0);
    double xy= y*x;
    return Dekker(x,y,xy)==0.0; //linked above
}
```

This idea can be simplified by keeping only the first few statements of the Dekker split and changing the constant `C` so that the split is between the first bit of the significand (1 by definition) and the last 52 (which are zero iff `x` is a power of two):

```
bool isPow2(double x){
    double px, qx, hx;
    double const C=0x10000000000001;
    px=x*C;
    qx=x-px;
    hx=px+qx;
    return hx==x;
}
```

This assumes that your compiler provides IEEE 754 binary64 semantics for floating-point operations.

If you really want to use this approach, and need a robust version that handles zeroes and negative numbers, you can wrap it so:

```
bool robustIsPow2(double x) {
  if (x <= 0.0) return false;
  if (x <= 1.0) return isPow2(x * (double)0x4000000000000000);
  return isPow2(x / (double)0x4000000000000000);
}
```

Comment: that code does not work either or the answer is not clear enough to extract some code from:
http://ideone.com/4HNo2E

Comment: @DarioOO Indeed, “x*std::nextafter(1.0,0.0)==x” does not implement “the multiplication of nextafter(1.0, 0.0) by x is exact”.

Comment: @DarioOO “operation • is exact” means that if you compute the exact error of the IEEE 754 version of • (that is, the difference between the real • and the IEEE 754 •), you find zero. Sorry to have confused you. Here is an implementation of the simpler solution I offer in the second part of my answer, with still the limitations that there must be no overflow or underflow and that the compiler must offer strict IEEE 754 binary64 semantics for * and +, and as such less recommendable than Alan Stokes's: http://ideone.com/3phnG7

Comment: Negative numbers are an issue here.  So are really huge powers of two like `0x1.0p+1022`.  I think you need a conditional if you're going to handle both the gradual underflow case and the really-huge-powers-of-two case at the same time.

Comment: @tmyklebu I really think what the OP wanted was a portable version of the four lines of code in his question, and `frexp` is exactly that, so it is hard to find motivation for getting the edge cases right. Ok, I'll revise my answer this evening.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Floating Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) page on wikipedia, double precision normally correspond to what you use : 53 bits for mantissa.

But you can also find an extended format (80 bits) with 64 bits of mantissa, 32 bits single precision float (24 bits of mantissa), quadruple precision (112 bits of mantissa), and probably other on less common architectures.

So as already said by Alan Stokes, the only reliable and portable way is the use of the frexp function.

Comment: There are also non-IEEE floating point machines out there, although they're now fairly unusual. C++ does not even mandate base 2 for floating point.

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns `true` on `-1`, so it doesn't work.  That's easy enough to fix, but your approach has other fundamental problems.

In any rounding mode, it will compute either infinity or the largest normal number when applied to the smallest positive nonzero subnormal.  Taking the product will result in either infinity or something much less than `1`.

In round-to-nearest mode, it also returns `true` on the `double` after `1`.  (And lots and lots and lots of other `double`s.)

In round-upward mode, say, it works for positive, normal floating-point numbers; if `x` is not a power of two, then `1/x` cannot be exactly represented so `flup(1/x)`, the floating-point number to which `1/x` rounds in round-upward mode, is strictly larger than `1/x`.  Then `x * flup(1/x))` is strictly larger than `x`, so `flup(x * flup(1/x))` is strictly larger than 1.  However, for a positive, normal power of two, both operations are exact.  The same holds for round-downward mode and round-toward-zero mode.

The following code appears to work in round-upward, round-downward, and round-toward-zero modes for IEEE 754 `double`s:

```
int p2(double d) {
  return d > 0 && 0x1.0p-51 / d * d == 0x1.0p-51;
}
```

The constant `0x1.0p-51` was chosen so that the conputation of `0x1.0p-51 / d * d` would neither overflow for the smallest subnormal nor overflow for the largest normal power of two.

I can compute `d` times the roundoff error in dividing `0x1.0p-51` by d, which is on the order of `0x1.0p-104`.  The following code works in all four rounding modes:

```
int p2(double d) {
  return d > 0 && fma(0x1.0p-51/d, d, -0x1.0p-51) == 0;
}
```

With all this said, you should use Alan Stokes's solution; `frexp` is designed for stuff like this and it behaves intelligently in all the weird cases.

Comment: Thanks, I confirm my approach was flawed and added few test cases based on your critique.